# Calculate within a column using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

This is what I got so far:

```
var="1.5"

echo "date,1%sa,comment" |
 awk -F ',' '{print $2}' |
 awk -v i="$var" -F '%' '{$1*=i; print $1}'

# prints: 1.5
```

I need to get the value to calculate with from a variable outside `awk` so using `-v`. In the code I use two awk commands to separate the number from the `%sa`. How can I combine those 2 commands and reprint the whole line like this:

```
date,1.5,comment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var="1.5"

echo "date,1%sa,comment" |
awk -F ',' -v OFS=',' -v i="$var" '{ split($2, a, "%"); $2 = a[1]*i; print }'
```

This uses commas for input and output separators and then splits the second field on `%`, sets it to the number in front of the `%` times the value of the variable passed into the program, and prints the modified record.